# Detecting Event Support in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, detection

So I have been racking my brain over this for quite some time. Here is the situation. I wan't to use events such as mouseup and mousedown when they are available. However, for iPhones these obviously have to be replaced with touchend and touchstart. What I am trying to do is detect if the two former events are supported, rather than if the touch events are supported. This is because Androids and other devices do support mouseup and mousedown.

At this point I have tried every detection method imaginable, including (type is the event type passed in):

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
eventName = 'on' + type;
var isSupported = (eventName in el);
if (!isSupported) {
  el.setAttribute(eventName, 'return;');
  isSupported = typeof el[eventName] == 'function';
}
```

And

```
if(document.hasOwnProperty('on' + type) 
  && typeof document['on' + type] !== 'undefined') {
  return true;
}
```

And

```
return 'on' + type in document.documentElement;
```

The problem is that each one of these methods seems to be evaluating to true on my trusty iPhone. I could really use some insight.

One requirement is the function has to take in a string for a type. I cannot do something like "document.onEvent". I have a collection of events to test and it should be dynamic anyway. No browser sniffing either.

I have looked at a few articles for these various ideas as well, so I have done my googling.

http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/ 
http://www.asiantravelhotel.com/javascript/onbeforeunload-support-detection.html

Comment: What do you want to do on mouseup/down? iPhone does support the events, but probably not in a way that you want.

Comment: I have tried this one before and it doesn't work. I was trying it on a `<script>` to detect support for `onerror`. It reported true for Opera and Firefox but never fired the handlers attached to actual failing scripts.

Comment: @Joseph that is exactly what is happening here.